# Aligning horizontally an inline-block

Tags: html, css

I have a div element which has the inline-block display property. I want to align it horizontally with the next code but it doesn't work.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is a random text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry I am not sure I understand. More clarification, maybe?

Comment: You want to center the div horizontally?

Comment: what is "the next code"? - you should add it to your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. The quickest way would be to replace `margin: auto;` with:

```
margin-left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Which will push it 50% to the right, relative to its parent, and then 50% (relative to itself) to the left, so it is perfectly centered.

Another way, if you're willing to change the CSS entirely, is to replace all your CSS with this:

```
div {
    text-align: center;
}
p {
    border: 3px solid red;
    padding: 15px 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Which pretty much moves all your code in the `div` over to the `p` and then applies `text-align: center;` to the parent div, meaning that every element inside the div is centered.

Comment: Another question: can you explain me why the margin:auto method doesn't work?

Comment: @CristiCazan For `margin: 0 auto;` (not `margin: auto;`) to work the element needs to have a specific width defined for them. Eg, `width: 500px;` or `min-width: 500px;` which you would apply to the `p` element. Having a set specific width isn't great for responsiveness, unless you're willing to put in a few media queries for it, too, so these other options are better. As noted on the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin#Horizontal_centering_with_margin_0_auto) for centering, you may also use `display: flex; justify-content: center;` on the parent `div`, instead.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
:root {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
:root {
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is a random text</p>
</div>
```